# Is the isomorphism class of Eichler order with prime level in $B_{p,\infty}$ with extra units at most unique?

Tags: quaternion-algebras

Let $B_{p, \infty}$ be the quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ ramified exactly at $p$ and $\infty$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an order in $B_{p, \infty}$. As we know, if $\mathcal{O}$ is maximal, then the isomorphism class of $\mathcal{O}$ with $|\mathcal{O}^{\times}|=4$ or $|\mathcal{O}^{\times}|=6$ is at most unique. Assume that $\mathcal{O}$ is an Eichler (or hereditary) order with prime level, whether the isomorphism class of $\mathcal{O}$ with $|\mathcal{O}^{\times}|=4$ or $|\mathcal{O}^{\times}|=6$ is at most unique or not?

Comment: Did you try to figure this out yourself by comparing class number and mass formulas?

Comment: Note that $p>3$ is a prime integer.